# レスポンシブ対応のドロップダウンメニューがうまく作れません。

Tags: javascript, html, css

コーディング初心者です。レスポンシブ対応のドロップダウンメニューがうまく作れません。
どこを直せば添付した画像の通りSP版PC版整ったかたちになるでしょうか？

```js
$(function(){
          // ハンバーガーメニュー
          $("#drawer_toggle").click(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass("open");
          $("#global_nav").toggleClass("sp_open");
          });
      });
```

```css
header {
  height: 80px;
}
header h1 {
  top: 24px;
  left: 25px;
}
header .logo img {
  width: 250px;
}
header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  opacity: 1;
}
header nav ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: unset;
  list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: relative;
}
header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #9c9b98;
  font-size: unset;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .3s;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #b99566;
}
header nav ul li:hover a {
color: #fff;
}

#drawer_toggle {
  display: none;
}
#key_visual {
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
main {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
main h2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#information {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#information ul {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
#information ul li time {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#information ul li p {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
}
#information ul li p::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#gourmet .container {
justify-content: space-between;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
padding: 10px 0;
}
#gourmet article {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  padding: 0;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  header {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
header h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 15px;
}
header .logo img {
    width: 200px;
}
header nav {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    /* 3. スライドメニューの場合 */
    right: -100%;
    transition: right .5s;
    /* ここまで */
}
/* 3. スライドメニューの場合 */
header nav.sp_open {
    right: 0;
}
/* ここまで */
header nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#drawer_toggle {
    z-index: 200;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
#drawer_toggle span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    left: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #666;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#drawer_toggle span:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#drawer_toggle span:last-child {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#drawer_toggle.open span {
    top: 29px;
    left: 14px;
    width: 35px;
    margin: 0;
}
#drawer_toggle.open span:first-child {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#drawer_toggle.open span:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
#drawer_toggle.open span:last-child {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
main {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
main h2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #b99566;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 40px;
}
main h2 span {
    display: none;
}
#key_visual {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1500px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#key_visual img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#information ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
#information ul li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#information ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f5f3f0;
}
#information ul li time {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
#information ul li p {
    line-height: 1.5;
}
#information ul li p::before {
    content: "▶︎";
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#gourmet .container {
    padding: 10px;
}
#gourmet h3 {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
#gourmet article {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#gourmet article figure {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#gourmet article figure img {
    width: 100%;
}
#gourmet article p {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
#gourmet article p::before {
    content: "-";
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#gourmet .box_ttl {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    border-left: 4px solid #402805;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#gourmet .area li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #b99566;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

```html
<nav id="global_nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home">ホーム</a></li>
                <li><a href="company">会社情報</a></li>
                <li><a href="service">事業案内</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="buying">買いたい</a></li>
            <li><a href="selling">売りたい</a></li>
            <li><a href="rent">借りたい</a></li>
            <li><a href="lend">貸したい</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
                <li><a href="inquiry">お問い合わせ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

[image: PC完成予定][image: SP完成予定][image: 現状]